# Get rows of only latest (overall) load

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, max

Here's my table:

```
EmpID | Rating | LoadID
-----------------------
  1       5        100
  1       7        101
  1       8        102
  2       6        100
  2       6        101
  3       4        102
```

I need to select only rows for the latest (overall) `LoadID`. Based on the above the latest(overall) `LoadID` is 102 so I need to have this result set:

```
EmpID | Rating | LoadID
-----------------------
  1        8      102
  3        4      102
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a sample of doing it with a CTE:

```
with RankCTE as
(
select
    EmpID
  , Rating
  , LoadID
  , Rank() over (order by LoadID desc) as R
from TABLE
)

select
    EmpID
  , Rating
  , LoadID
from RankCTE
where R = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a variable or use a nested query:

The following is untested and might have syntax errors:

```
SELECT
    t.[EmpId]
    ,t.[Rating]
    ,t.[LoadID]
FROM
    yourTable t
WHERE
    LoadId = (
    SELECT
        TOP 1 t.[LoadID]
    FROM
        yourTable t
    ORDER BY t.[LoadID] DESC
    )
```

Comment: That's a bit verbose and the subquery might make it a bit slow. I'd recommend using a CTE.

Comment: You're right, the nested query certainly isn't elegant. That's what Entity Framework does to the SQL area of the brain.

Comment: Forgive my noobness... how can i do this using CTE?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx Although @FarligOpptreden deserves the reputation for the suggestion.

Comment: Haha! Thanks StuperUser. :P @tonson7 check my answer for implementing this with a CTE

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
declare @T table (EmpID int, Rating int, LoadID int)
insert into @T values
(  1,       5,        100),
(  1,       7,        101),
(  1,       8,        102),
(  2,       6,        100),
(  2,       6,        101),
(  3,       4,        102)

select T.*
from @T as T
where
  LoadID in (select max(LoadID)
             from @T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the same using a CTE

```
;WITH TblCTE as(
SELECT  [EmpId],[Rating],[LoadID],RANK() over (order by [LoadID] DESC) r
FROM    yourTable)
SELECT  * FROM TblCTE WHERE r=1
```